# Google Smart Lock remove on login form

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-select

How can I remove this Google Smart Lock in my form for login.

Heres my HTML code

```
    <form novalidate autocomplete="new-password">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="pEmployeeID" class="form-control" placeholder="Employee ID" ng-model="portal.loginData.employeeID" ng-keypress="portal.employeeIdEnter($event)" ng-minlength="3" ng-required="true" maxlength="4" ng-trim="false" autocomplete="off" numeric-only />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" id="pEmployeePin" class="form-control" placeholder="PIN Number" ng-model="portal.loginData.employeePin" ng-required="true" maxlength="4" ng-trim="false" numeric-only autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="portal.ok()"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

I already tried `autocomplete="off"` or `autocomplete="new-password"` but still issue occurs.

I want to remove this because it has an issue in my ui-select wherein the saved value will be the default on page load of my ui-select.

[image: How to remove thi]

Comment: Isn't this rather a browser setting problem than an html one?

Comment: yes but i need to handle this one since it will cause an issue on my ui-select